# Setting scroll extent of ScrollViewer in wpf

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, datatemplate, scroll, itemscontrol

I am using a ScrollViewer in WPF. My XAML is as follows ::

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="ScrollProcess">

   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock>Test Text</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>

</ScrollViewer>
```

**I want to know how to set the scrollbar to the selected `TextBlock` (say around 25 TextBlocks gets displayed. I have to move the scrollbar to 15th TextBlock)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textBox15.BringIntoView();
```

[`FrameworkElement.BringIntoView Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview.aspx)

Comment: Superb ! It works great yippie !!!! I manipulated by code a bit to add your code and by using attached properties I was able to achieve my requirement.